# laravel 4 cronjob to trigger controller methods

Tags: laravel, cron

any advice how to trigger a controller method with a cronjob?

I've created an artisan command

```
public function schedule(Schedulable $scheduler)
{

    return $scheduler->everyMinutes(1);

}

/**
 * Execute the console command.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function fire()
{
    if (Auth::check())
    {
        $users = Auth::user();
        Log::info($users);
    }
}
```

Instead of logging I want to call a Controller Method. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Better practice is to create [trait](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) or [helper](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/50/creating-a-helpers-file) and use it both inside you controller and artisan commands.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you're trying to call a controller method from elsewhere is indicative that your controller has too much responsibility. Ideally you should move the functionality elsewhere such that both the controller and the job can access it.

However, if you don't want to do that you could create a request and use the router to dispatch it internally.

```
$request = Request::create('uri/of/controller', 'GET', $params);

return Route::dispatch($request)->getContent();
```

You may also be able to use the Container to get an instance of the controller and call the method directly.

```
App::make('YourController')->yourMethod($params);
```